# Spring Boot application connects to Topic in JCAPS

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a Spring Boot Application. I have connected to ActiveMQ topic successfully and now I'm trying to connect to JCAPS.

I have `stcjms.jar` and `stcjcs.jar` in my classpath.

I'm using the following properties to initialize the connection factory:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=com.stc.jms.jndispi.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=stcms://XXX:12345 
topic.topicConnFactory=connectionfactories/topicconnectionfactory
topic.topicName=topics/topDest
```

But, it's throwing an exception:
 `ClassNotFoundException : com.stc.jms.jndispi.InitialContextFactory`

I'm new to Spring Boot and JCAPS. Any help is appreciated.